# I want to install JDK for Debian using ARM64 but I got todpkg: error: archive 'jdk-20.0.2' is not a regular file, how do I fix?

Tags: java, oracle, wget, tar, dpkg

I tried to install Java IDK using https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk18-linux and wget as well as uncompressing it using tar but when I tried to `sudo apt dpkg install` on it, it would result in the error:

```
dpkg: error: 
archive 'jdk-20.0.2' is not a regular file.
```

What does it mean and how can I fix it?

1. Installed https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk18-linux using wget
2. Got back jdk-20_linux-aarch64_bin.tar.gz, then went to Downloads directory
3. Unpackaged jdk-20_linux-aarch64_bin.tar.gz using tar zxvf
4. Tried to sudo dpkg -i jdk-20_linux-aarch64_bin.tar.gz
5. "dpkg: error: archive 'jdk-20.0.2' is not a regular file"

Comment: Can you use dpkg to install files other than .deb? Is there some reason you aren't using apt?

Comment: Yes why are you installing manually?

Comment: You should have downloaded the file ending with deb if you are installing using Debian tools like dpkg. The tar.gz file contains the binary distribution and you could put it anywhere (in theory) on your file system and just add the bin folder to your path.

Comment: Consider that Java 20 is a short-lived version of Java, not suitable for serious usage. I would stick with 8, 11, or 17.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Oracle does not provide .deb packages for AArch64.

Comment: Isn't [Arm64](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/openjdk-17-jdk) the same thing?

Comment: I tried to use apt but it said that it was not a deb package

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: It's a ChromeOS with Debian 11 Bullseye

Comment: So `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk`

Comment: If you absolutely must have 20, then there's [this](https://download.bell-sw.com/java/20.0.2+10/bellsoft-jdk20.0.2+10-linux-aarch64.deb)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install a tar.gz file using dpkg — it's not a .deb package, and dpkg does not know what to do with it.

If you only need to install Java for your user and not systemwide, you could do the following:

```
tar -xzvf jdk-20_linux-aarch64_bin.tar.gz
```

This would extract the contents of the archive into a directory called `jdk-20.0.2`. Now create the `.bin/java` directory in your home folder:

```
mkdir -p ~/.bin/java
```

Now copy the `jdk-20.0.2` folder into your new folder:

```
cp -rp jdk-20.0.2 ~/.bin/java
```

Now you will need to edit your shell configuration file, it should be .bashrc by default:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Add the following lines to this config file:

```
PATH="$HOME/.bin/java/jdk-20.0.2/bin:$PATH"
export JAVA_HOME=$HOME/.bin/java/jdk-20.0.2
```

Press Ctrl-o to save the changes and Ctrl-x to exit the editor.

Now you need to source your shell configuration file:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Verify that you can run the Java VM by using the following command:

```
java --version
```

Now you can delete the file you downloaded and the unpacked folder:

```
rm jdk-20_linux-aarch64_bin.tar.gz
rm -rf jdk-20.0.2/
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I always saw the console recommend a PATH file whenever I would use python, but I didn't knew that it could do this.. How does the PATH file work?

Comment: @TylerRoberts - it's not a file, it's an environment variable. It lists all the directories where the system would look for an executable file when you issue a command. So for example, if your PATH is /bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin, it would look for executables in those folders in this exact order. When you add a directory to this list, you basically make executables located in this directory available as console commands.

Comment: So when I use java --version, the terminal looks for the file immediately on the PATH?

Comment: Essentially, yes

Comment: But if you're unfamiliar with all this then all the more reason to let the package manager install the JDK as it will do all that for you